# How to change the length of scrollbar in Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

```
import Tkinter as tk

class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.canvas=tk.Canvas(self,scrollregion=(0,0,1000,1000))
        self.canvas.grid()

        self.canvas.create_line(0,0,1000,1000)

        self.scroll=tk.Scrollbar(self,orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.scroll.grid()

GUI().mainloop()
```

the scrollbar seems to be too short,how to change its length with grid layout class?

Comment: Can you add some context as to what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide arguments for the `grid` method that specify how you want the widget to fit into the layout.  The `sticky` argument is the key here.  It accepts cardinal coordinates in various formats, and these coordinates tell Tkinter which sides of the widget should "stick" to the corresponding sides of the grid cell.  In your case, you want the east (E) and west (W) sides to stick, so your `grid` call for the scrollbar could be formatted in several ways:

(using individual global variables from the Tkinter module)

```
self.scroll.grid(sticky=tk.E + tk.W)
```

(using special combo global variables from the module)

```
self.scroll.grid(sticky=tk.EW)
```

(using a string)

```
self.scroll.grid(sticky="EW")
```